# How to react in telegram-bot after executing a request to mongoDb?

Tags: node.js, telegram

How to react in telegram-bot after executing a request to mongoDb?

I'm developing a telegram bot on ***nodejs, mongoDb***, using ***node-telegram-bot-api*** as a library

The task is to write a chat to the user after accessing mongoDb, I am trying to pass the next() function, but it does not work and the application crashes

```
app.get("/posts/:user", PostController.GetPostsByUserId, async () => {
  await bot.sendMessage(chatId, `My text`); // node-telegram-bot-api
}); // request

export const GetPostsByUserId = async (req, res, bot) => {
  try {
    const posts = await PostModel.find({ username: req.params.username });

    await bot();
    return res.json(posts);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Не удалось найти" });
  }
}; // request controller
```